# What is the use of a custom unique_ptr deleter that calls delete?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

In the C++ samples provided by [NVidia's TensorRT library](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt), there is a file named `common.h` that contains definitions of structures used throughout the examples.

Among other things, the file contains [the following definitions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/22.05/samples/common/common.h#L384):

```
struct InferDeleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T* obj) const
    {
        delete obj;
    }
};

template <typename T>
using SampleUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T, InferDeleter>;
```

The `SampleUniquePtr` alias is used throughout the code samples to wrap various pointers to interface classes returned by some functions, e.g. `SampleUniquePtr<INetworkDefinition>(builder->createNetworkV2(0));`

My question is, in what practical aspects are `std::unique_ptr` and `SampleUniquePtr` different? The behavior of `SampleUniquePtr` is pretty much what I would expect from `std::unique_ptr`, at least now. Could it be for compatibility with old versions of C++?

Comment: Dunno what their intention was, but that looks like something I might do as a way to insert a debug-print for tracing/troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: If you look at the file history, you can see that the deleter behaved differently originally. Then it was changed to just call `delete`, effectively equivalent to `std::default_delete`. I assume they simple did this change in such a way so that it wouldn't affect ABI or to have least impact required on the rest of the code.

Comment: And additionally they use `InferDeleter` in more places where `std::default_delete` wouldn't work as nicely, because the latter takes the type as class template argument, but they want to a have a generic functor, e.g. https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/blob/main/samples/sampleUffFasterRCNN/sampleUffFasterRCNN.cpp#L186. All of this seems to be for the samples only anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [history](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/commit/aff45dd56553f09dcaf3ebeaf58ef03347bebfbf#) I see it was for a while

```
template <typename T>
void InferDeleter::operator()(T* obj) const
{
    if (obj)
    {
        obj->destroy();
    }
}
```

Then they declared [`destroy()`](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/commit/aff45dd56553f09dcaf3ebeaf58ef03347bebfbf#diff-06572a96a58dc510037d5efa622f9bec8519bc1beab13c9f251e97e657a9d4edR29) methods deprecated:

> - Destructors for classes with `destroy()` methods were previously protected. They are now public, enabling use of smart pointers for these classes. The `destroy()` methods are deprecated.

Although it is deprecated, it is still not removed and the old ABI `InferDeleter` should be kept for backward compatibility for applications linked with the old TensorRT. Thus they are using since recently

```
template <typename T>
void InferDeleter::operator()(T* obj) const
{
    delete obj;
}
```

not removing the `struct InferDeleter` and `using SampleUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T, InferDeleter>`. But it may be removed in the future. When they remove `struct InferDeleter` and change `using SampleUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<T>`, it will make TensorRT library incompatible with old software.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the time to scan through the entirety of the linked library, so there is a chance I'm wrong on this count.

But, what you're seeing is probably a *default* implementation that's used as a fallback for any type that doesn't need special handling.

The Library Implementor always has the option of specializing this function in the situation where they're dealing with a type that actually does need special handling, which is probably pretty common for a library made by Nvidia (and therefore probably meant to interact with the GPU).

```
class GPUResource {
//...
~GPUResource() noexcept {} //Does NOT perform the special handling, for whatever library-specific reason
};

template<>
void InferDeleter::operator()<GPUResource>(GPUResource * obj) {
    performSpecialCleanupOnGPUResource(obj->handle);
    delete obj;
}
```

In practice, this kind of stuff always smells like an anti-pattern (are you *sure*, Library Implementor, that you couldn't do the cleanup in the destructor of this object??) but if they had good reasons for separating out the logic like this, the way they've defined `InferDeleter` permits them this kind of flexibility.

Comment: Nice point. Though, couldn't the same effect be achieved by using `std::unique_ptr` and overloading `std::delete`?

Answer (score 1):

The example looks pointless as that is exactly what I expect the default deleter to do.

But maybe this is better (untested):

```
#include <vector>
struct VectorDeleter
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(std::vector<T*> *v) const
    {
        for(auto p : *v) delete p;
        delete v;
    }
};

template <typename V>
using UniquePtrVector = std::unique_ptr<V, VectorDeleter>;
```

When you have a vector of pointers (to e.g. polymorphic classes) you have to delete the objects the vector points to when the vector is deleted. The VectorDeleter does that before the vector itself is deleted.